# RSA - Under What Circumstances does Encryption Key Also Decrypt Cyphertext?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I used primes $p = 7$, $q = 13$, to get $n = 91$ and $\phi(n) = 72$.

I chose $E=19<\phi(n)$, but found that $D=19$, which meant $x^E=x$ $(mod$ $n)$, i.e. the encryption is just the identity transformation!

I encountered the same issue with $E=17$.

**My first question then** is when you find $E$ and $D$ in practice, is it a case of trial and error until you find $E$ and $D$ that do encrypt the text?  Is there some better way than trial and error?

Then I tried $E=11$ and got $D=59$.  However, here I discovered that $x^{11}$ $(mod$ $91)$ and $x^{59}$ $(mod$ $91)$ are actually the same function, as well as being inverses of each other.  I don't recall reading anywhere that the encryption key can also sometimes be the decryption key.

Further investigation showed that $x^{59}$ $(mod$ $91)$ may be split into $(x^{7})^7x^{10}$ $(mod$ $7)=x^{11}$ $(mod$ $7)$ and $(x^{13})^4x^7$ $(mod$ $13)=x^{11}$ $(mod$ $13)$, by the CRT and FLT, which $x^{11}$ $(mod$ $91)$ can also be split up into.  Therefore they are the same function.

**So my second question is** under what conditions does the encryption key also act as the decryption key?  Again in practice, is it just trial and error until you find keys without this drawback?

**A third question also could be**, is there something about $n=91$ that makes it impossible to use for RSA?

Thank you for your time.  This is my first time using Stack Exchange so I hope to have posed an original and clear question.

Comment: In the first example, you do *not* get $x^E\equiv x\bmod n$.

Comment: You get $D=E$ when $D^2\equiv1\bmod{\phi(n)}$.

Comment: The original version of your question was better.

Comment: Thank you Randall for taking the time to explore this for me.  You have covered all the points I made.  I think the final result you state is quite useful.

Comment: In practice, people don't choose a random $e$, but $e=2^{16}+1$ (an industry standard), as this ensures fast exponentiation and as this $e$ is prime, it will almost surely be relatively prime with $\phi(n)$; $d$ is then computed and typically (we're talking 100's of digits numbers here, eg. around 616 for 2048 bit moduli) is a lot larger than $e$. $e=d$ never occurs in practical cases, just in small toy examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know some basic group/ring theory (or maybe just quadratic residues) this is all easily explainable.  Recall that once $E$ is selected, $D$ is dictated as $E^{-1} \bmod \varphi(n)$.  In other words, $E$ is selected from the group of units $\mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(n)}^*$ and $D$ is then its inverse in this group. (As pointed out, your edit with $E=D=19$ is wrong regarding $x \mapsto x^E$ being the identity map.)

Now, how large is the group of units $\mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(n)}^*$?  By some basic ring theory, this group has size $\varphi(\varphi(n))$.  [In general, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_k$ has $\varphi(k)$ units.]  For example, with $n=91$, $\varphi(n) = 72$ and sure enough, working mod $72$ there are $\varphi(\varphi(91)) = \varphi(72)=24$ units.  In short, you only have $24$ valid choices for $E$ when you work RSA mod $91$.

Your (original) first question was, paraphrased:  **is $D=E$ always a possibility?  And why does this happen?**  Here is the relevant fact for your question on why $D=E$ is possible.  (In fact, it is inescapable:  no RSA moduli avoid this phenomenon completely.)

**Theorem:** When $m \geq 3$, the value of $\varphi(m)$ is even.

The only RSA modulus for which this is false is $n=6$, which gives $\varphi(\varphi(6))=1$, odd.  **For all other RSA moduli $n$, we have that $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ must always be even.**

Hence the group of units $\mathbb{Z}_{\varphi(n)}^*$, from which you selected $E$, has even order.  *Now any group of even order has at least one (probably more) element of order $2$ (meaning $x^2=1$), and such elements are there own inverses (meaning $x=x^{-1}$).*  This is what happened in your example.  If you get out your modular calculator, set the modulus to $72$ and ask for the multiplicative inverse of $19$, you will see that the answer is itself.  This must **always** happen for at least one key-choice of $E$ because this group has even order.

If this bothers you, then don't use it.  Check that $D$ is not $E$, and if it was, then choose again.  By probability, it won't happen again.

In your second example, you chose $E=11$ and $D=E^{-1} \bmod 72$ is in fact $D=59$.  Nice observation that exponentiation by each results in the *same* function; this is insightful on your part.  I'm not sure of a completely general set of conditions that explain or predict this based on $n$, $p$, $q$, etc.  I will point out that, in your example, $n=91=7 \cdot 13$, and $p-1=6$ divides $q-1=12$.

**Proposition:**  Suppose we have an RSA setup $n=pq$ with $E$ and $D$ correctly chosen.  Then the encryption function $f: x \mapsto x^E \bmod n$ is the same as the decryption function $g: x \mapsto x^D \bmod n$ if $D$ is simultaneously congruent to $E$ modulo $p-1$ and $q-1$.

The proof of this is basically the same as the proof that RSA works.  You can write $D=E + k(p-1)$ for some $k$, and $D  = E + j(q-1)$ for some $j$.  Show that $x^D \equiv x^E \bmod n$ by arguing mod $p$ and mod $q$ in cases.  You'll need to consider when $x$ is divisible by $p$ and not $q$, the vice versa, then neither.  It will all work because of Euler's theorem.

It gets worse in some cases.  If we additionally knew that $p-1$ divides $q-1$, then we don't have to check both congruences above.  This is your "problem," since $91 = 7 \cdot 13$ and $7-1$ divides $13-1$.

**Corollary:**  Suppose we have an RSA setup $n=pq$ where $p < q$ and with $E$ and $D$ correctly chosen.  Suppose also that $p-1$ divides $q-1$.  Then the encryption function $f: x \mapsto x^E \bmod n$ is the same as the decryption function $g: x \mapsto x^D \bmod n$ if $D$ is congruent to $E$ modulo $q-1$.

*Proof.*  If $q-1$ divides $D-E$ then $p-1$ also divides $D-E$, so the previous result applies.  $\Box$

*Note:*  This is exactly your situation.  You have $E=11$ and $D=59$, and $D-E=48$ is divisible by $q-1=12$.

Finally, this business of $p-1$ dividing $q-1$ is not sufficient to create this behavior.  So, whatever is going on with $n=91$, this isn't the whole explanation.

**Example:** With $p=11$ and $q=71$ we have $n=781$, $\varphi(n)=700$, and $p-1$ dividing $q-1$.  However, plenty of key choices do NOT result in $x \mapsto x^E$ agreeing with $x \mapsto x^D \bmod n$.  One example is $(E,D) = (3, 467)$.

There is one general thing you can say about the encryption function agreeing with the decryption function.  Let $f : x \mapsto x^E$ be the encryption, and $g: x \mapsto x^D$ be the decryption, all mod $n$. We have $f \circ g =1=g \circ f$ by design.  Certainly if $D=E$ then we'll have $f=g$, but as you've pointed out this need not be necessary.  If $f=g$ this will say $f \circ f=1$.  The converse is also true by uniqueness of inverses for bijective functions:  $f \circ f =1$ implies that encryption is decryption.  However, $f \circ f =1$ means that $f(f(x))=(x^E)^E = x^{E^2} \equiv x \bmod n$.  However, we are now *multiplying* up in the exponent, so we should work mod $\varphi(\varphi(n))$, not just $\varphi(n)$.  Hence we would have $f=g$ if $E^2 \equiv 1 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(n))$.

Sure enough, this is your example!  With $n=91$, $\varphi(\varphi(n))=24$, and with $E=11$ we get $E^2 = 121 \equiv 1 \bmod 24$.